# Generating a string with python using loops with logic conditions issues against join function alternative?

Tags: python, string

I coded a function in order to generate Lagrange interpolation expressions.

So I got:

```
def polinomioLagrange(Xs, Ys, t):

    for k in range(len(Xs)):

        if k >0: 
            expresion = expresion + '+' + str(Ys[k]) + '*'
        elif k==0:
            expresion = expresion + str(Ys[k]) + '*'

        expresion = expresion + '('

        for i in range(len(Xs)):
            if k==i:
                continue 

            expresion = expresion + '(' + '3' + '-' + str(Xs[i]) + ')'

            if k != len(Xs)-1 and i!= len(Xs)-1:
                expresion=expresion+'*'

        expresion = expresion + '/'

        for i in range(len(Xs)):
            if k==i:
                continue 
            expresion = expresion + '(' + str(Xs[k]) + '-' + str(Xs[i]) + ')'

            if i != len(Xs)-1 and k != len(Xs)-1:
                expresion=expresion+'*'             

    print expresion
```

I'm calling it, for example by: `polinomioLagrange([0,1,2,4],[7,0,-1,63],3)` and I'm getting outputs similar to:

```
7*((3-1)*(3-2)*(3-4)/(0-1)*(0-2)*(0-4))+0*((3-0)*(3-2)*(3-4)/(1-0)*(1-2)*(1-4))+-1*((3-0)*(3-1)*(3-4)/(2-0)*(2-1)*(2-4))+63*((3-0)(3-1)(3-2)/(4-0)(4-1)(4-2))
```

As it can be seen, there are not asterisks at the last term:

```
63*((3-0)(3-1)(3-2)/(4-0)(4-1)(4-2))
```

That's because of

```
if k != len(Xs)-1 and i!= len(Xs)-1:
    expresion=expresion+'*'
```

But I've really played with indexes and got not exactly the result I want:

```
7*((3-1)*(3-2)*(3-4)/(0-1)*(0-2)*(0-4))+0*((3-0)*(3-2)*(3-4)/(1-0)*(1-2)*(1-4))+-1*((3-0)*(3-1)*(3-4)/(2-0)*(2-1)*(2-4))+63*((3-0)*(3-1)*(3-2)/(4-0)*(4-1)*(4-2))
```

What logic condition would do the job and, what's more, what's the easiest way, using more sophisticated python functions like `join` to get it done?

Closest I got, looping and changing logic conditions was:

```
if i != len(Xs)-1:
    expresion=expresion+'*'
```

Getting:

```
7*((3-1)*(3-2)*(3-4)/(0-1)*(0-2)*(0-4))+0*((3-0)*(3-2)*(3-4)/(1-0)*(1-2)*(1-4))+-1*((3-0)*(3-1)*(3-4)/(2-0)*(2-1)*(2-4))+63*((3-0)*(3-1)*(3-2)*/(4-0)*(4-1)*(4-2)*)
```

***Almost correct***, excepting for `...)*/(...` and `...4-2)*)`

Just for the record, this is what I'm coding:
[image: Lagrange general formula]
[image: Expanded formula]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're making this a lot harder than it needs to be.  Rather than building strings, simply build symbolic expressions.  We can implement `l` and `L` directly:

```
from sympy import Symbol, prod

def lag_l(xx, j):
    x = Symbol("x")
    parts = ((x - x_i) / (xx[j] - x_i) for i, x_i in enumerate(xx) if i != j)
    return prod(parts)

def lag_L(xx, yy):
    return sum(y*lag_l(xx, j) for j, y in enumerate(yy))

def lag_fn(xx, yy, x):
    return lag_L(xx, yy).subs({'x': x})
```

after which we can get the basis functions:

```
>>> lag_l([1,2,3], 0)
(-x + 2)*(-x/2 + 3/2)
>>> lag_l([1,2,3], 1)
(-x + 3)*(x - 1)
>>> lag_l([1,2,3], 2)
(x/2 - 1/2)*(x - 2)
```

the full interpolating polynomial:

```
>>> lag_L([1,2,3],[1,4,9])
(-x + 2)*(-x/2 + 3/2) + 4*(-x + 3)*(x - 1) + 9*(x/2 - 1/2)*(x - 2)
```

and we can call the function (here wrapped as `lag_fn`):

```
>>> lag_fn([1,2,3],[1,4,9], 3)
9
```

.. of course the interpolating polynomial can be simplified a lot:

```
>>> from sympy import simplify
>>> simplify(lag_L([1,2,3],[1,4,9]))
x**2
```

Comment: I'd give you +50 if I could